# "ErrorMessage: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error." error message from Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, camera, photo

I'm coding a cross platform app and trying to create a camera preview page where users can see the live camera view. I'm using Xamarin Community Toolkit CameraView and am stuck with a problem. This is my code for the XAML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.CameraPreview"
             
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="cameraGrid">
            <xct:CameraView x:Name="xctCameraView"
                            CaptureMode="Photo"
                            MediaCaptured="MediaCaptured"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="15" x:Name="videoFrame" WidthRequest="48" Padding="7">
                        <Label Text="Video" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="videoLabel" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="15" x:Name="pictureFrame" WidthRequest="48" Padding="7">
                        <Label Text="Picture" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="pictureLabel" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                <ImageButton Clicked="CapturePhoto" HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="captureBtn" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the C# code for the CameraPreview class that takes care of taking the photo and changing the photo into byte and sending it to another page:

```
private void CapturePhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isPictureSelected)
            {
                if (xctCameraView != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"xctCameraView is not null");
                    xctCameraView.Shutter();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"camera picture taken");
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Error", "Camera view is not available.", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
    private void MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (xctCameraView.CaptureMode)
            {
                default:
                case CameraCaptureMode.Default:

                case CameraCaptureMode.Photo:
                    Debug.WriteLine($"media captured is passed");
                    if (e.Image != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"e.Image is not null");
                        var imageSource = (StreamImageSource)e.Image;
                        using (var stream = imageSource.Stream(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                        {
                            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine($"var memoryStream = new MemoryStream() went through");
                                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                                photoData = memoryStream.ToArray();
                                // Use the byte array 'photoData' as needed
                                Debug.WriteLine($"navigating to EditPostPage");
                                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                                {
                                    Navigation.PushAsync(new EditPostPage(userId, textId, photoData));
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;


                case CameraCaptureMode.Video:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when I take a photo it works since `Debug.WriteLine($"camera picture taken");` is shown in the output. However, somehow `MediaCaptured(object sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)` doesn't go through because none of the debug statements show up on the output. Instead after the picture is taken, there is an error message saying "[0:] CameraView: Error camera access" and "ErrorMessage: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error." What is the problem? I tried to restart the app, the emulator, and change it to a different device but the error message keeps showing up in the debug output.

Comment: `MediaCapturedEventArgs` contains a `string path` property and a `byte[] imageData` property.  See the [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/CameraViewPage.xaml.cs#L70)

Comment: @Jason I tried using MediaCapturedEventArgs and I coded so that MediaCaptured will take the "e.Image" and convert it to byte array and navigate to a new page with the byte. but somehow every time I take a picture it automatically displays the photo to the screen instead of navigating to the new page with the byte imageData. I couldn't figure out why it automatically displays the image so I deleted MediaCapturedEventArgs but by any chance would you know why whenever I take the photo it just shows up on the screen automatically?

Comment: if you want help solving **that problem**, [edit] your question to include the relevant code and description of the problem

Comment: @Jason I edited my question and added the verson when I add 'MediaCapturedEventArgs ' to the code. but some how the code doesn't go through MediaCapturedEventArgs when photo is taken.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Does `MediaCaptured` fire?  Does `e` contain data?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Jason Sorry for the confusion. `MediaCaptured` does not file and there is an error saying `[0:] CameraView: Error camera access. ErrorMessage: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error` in the debug output. this message shows up after I take a picture from the `CapturePhoto` method. And because of that error, `MediaCaptured` doesn't fire.

Comment: Then you should probably focus on that problem.  Search the XCT source for that error message; look for known issues in the repo; or file a new issue with the details of the problem

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not?  And if not what platform did you use?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT the issue has not been solved but once I tested on the physical device it worked well. I was working on the emulator but anytime I try to use CameraView, the emulator doesn't let me us it and give me that Camera Error. I code for cross platform but the emulator is pixel 5, API 33, Android. The physical device I'm using is Samsung, API 33, Android.

Comment: You may try: 1. Check the Camera Permission in AndroidMenifest; 2. In Visual Studio, Open Tools-> Android AVD , edit the emulator front camera and back camera to emulated.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT It worked when I edited the emulator front camera and back camera to emulated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are using a webcam on your development computer to simulate the back-facing camera on the emulated device, this value must be set to webcamn, where n selects the webcam (if you have only one webcam, choose webcam0). If set to emulated, the emulator simulates the camera in software. To disable the back-facing camera, set this value to none. If you enable the back-facing camera, be sure to also enable hw.camera.

You could try the following method:

Click on Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager. Then edit the Android emulator, set the `hw.camera.back` and `hw.camera.front` to `emulated`.

For more info, you could refer to [Editing Android Virtual Device Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-properties?pivots=windows).